# jQuery ajax from localhost:3000 api

Tags: jquery, node.js, api, rest, express

I made a restful API in a folder called (rest), it connects with port 3000 on my `localhost` at ..... http://localhost:3000/api/products.
also i made a jQuery logging application in a folder called (logs) doing an Ajax call to retrieve data from the API, adding new users and so on..
i run my app on browser-sync which runs on another port and so far i can't connect to API because i don't know what path URL shall i connect to.
 please can u help me in two things:

1. where to place these two folders (rest) , (logs)?
2. what URL for the API (running on port:3000)?

**my jquery app code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--------------------------- Meta tags -------------------->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Logs</title>



    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-55Jz3pBCF8z9jBO1qQ7cIf0L+neuPTD1u7Ytzrp2dqo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Jquery css ui -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- My stile link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First name</th> <th>Last name</th> </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="user">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-success getUsers"> Get Users </button>
            <form class= "form-inline">
                <input id="id" class="form-group" placeholder="ID">
                <input id="firstName" class="form-group" placeholder="First name">
                <input id="lastName" class="form-group" placeholder="Last name">
                <button class="btn btn-success addUsers"> Add a user</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var $user = $('.user');
        var $id = $('#id');
        var $firstName = $('#firstName');
        var $lastName = $('#lastName');
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $('.getUsers').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: '/api/products',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(users){
                    $.each(users, function(i, user){
                        $user.append('<tr><td>'+ user.id +'</td> <td>'+ user.firstName +'</td> <td>' +user.lastName + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $('.addUsers').click(function(){
            var $newUser = {
                id: $id.val(),
                firstName: $firstName.val(),
                lastName: $lastName.val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '/api/products',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $newUser,
                success: function(newUser){
                        $user.append('<tr><td>'+ newUser.id +'</td> <td>'+ newUser.firstName +'</td> <td>' +newUser.lastName + '</td></tr>');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        });
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

my api code:

/*************** server.js ************************/

```
    // DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');

// EXPRESS
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());  

// ROUTES
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api')); 

// START SERVER
app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is working on port 3000,yes');
```

/**************** api.js *****************************/

```
// DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// MODELS
var Product = require('../models/product');

// ROUTES
Product.methods(['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']);
Product.register(router, '/products');

// RETURN ROUTER
module.exports = router;
```

/************* product.js ******************/

```
// DEPENDENCIES
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// SCHEMA
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    mark: Number
});

// return model
module.exports = restful.model('Products', productSchema);
```

note: i`m too new to backend.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok, i replaced index.html which uses jquery ajax .. inside rest/routes at the same level of api.js  , i also changed api port to 3002 because 3000 was busy with browser-sync  ,, now i`m getting this error :XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3002/api/products. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

Your server must be enabled [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) To do this, you can use [CORS Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Install this module with `npm install cors`, add to dependencies `var cors = require('cors');`

And just change your `app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));` to `app.use('/api', cors(), require('./routes/api'));`

If you want to enable CORS for all routes, after include module write `app.use(cors())`